# ¿Como enviar un array via postman y recibirlo de forma correcta en OpenApi3.0 python?

Tags: python, api, postman

Estoy tratando de enviar un arreglo de emails por un form-data en postman, recibirlo en un esquema en python e imprimir los emails, pero algo me esta dando error por eso solicito ayuda, adjunto el esquema y el path ademas de una imagen de postman de como envio el array, cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

```
        openapi: 3.0.0
      version: 0.0.1
    servers:
      - url: https://localhost:3005
    components:
      schemas:
        email:
          type: object
          properties:
            receivers:
              type: array
              items:
                type: string
            header:
              type: string
            message:
              type: string
            file1:
              type: string
              format: binary
            file2:
              type: string
              format: binary
 paths:
    /api/email/{id}:
    post:
      tags:
      - email data
      summary: Send a email
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/email'
      operationId: routes.email.route_send_email
      parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        description: sender company ID
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: Everything is ok
        500:
          description: there was an error starting the facial recognition system
```

[image: postman-enviando-arreglo]

Comment: Tienes un error 400, eso significa qué o bien tu url está apuntando mal ¿podrías darnos parte del código o explicarnos cómo recoges los datos en Python? Así podría ayudarte más

Comment: Esa es la entrada de los datos, se espessifica un esquema en una archivo .yaml, se envian los datos via postman y luego en paths se espesifica la ruta del api que va a recibir ese tipo de datos y se da el esquema como referencia del formato de los datos